# Show that if 5 integers are selected from the first 8 positive integers, there must be a pair of these integers with a sum equal to 9. (Pigeonhole)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> Show that if 5 integers are selected from the first 8 positive integers, there must be a pair of these integers with a sum equal to 9.

The question calls for the use of the pigeonhole principle.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Divide the 8 integers into 4 groups.
Pigeons N = 5 integers
Pigeonholes k = 4 groups
⌈N/k⌉ = ⌈5/4⌉ = 2
```

Since it's stated that "there must be a pair of these integers with a sum equal to 9", does that mean it should be `⌈N/k⌉ = 1`? I'm not quite sure how to apply the pigeonhole principle here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to construct your subsets so that if you select both members of that subset you will obtain a sum of $9$.

In this case, we can construct the subsets $\{1, 8\}, \{2, 7\}, \{3, 6\}, \{4, 5\}$.  Since we are selecting five elements and there are only four subsets, we must select
$$\left\lceil \frac{5}{4}\right\rceil = 2$$
members from at least one of these subsets.  Since the sum of the elements in each subset is $9$, we are guaranteed to select a pair of integers whose sum is $9$.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks for the explanation, makes it a lot clearer to understand :)